# VB.NET looping through Access Database

Tags: database, vb.net

In a VB.NET how can I loop through an an Access database without loading it to a `DataGridView` or loading it to a `DataGridView` and unload it after a comparison function finshed its work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using DataReader you can loop thru data, one row at a time without necessity of loading entire result set into DataTable/GridView.

Example usage (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
Public Sub ReadData(ByVal connectionString As String, _
    ByVal queryString As String)
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand(queryString, connection)

        connection.Open()

        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Console.WriteLine(reader(0).ToString())
        End While
        reader.Close()
    End Using 
End Sub
```

You pass connection string to your MS Access Database, and SELECT query to run. Example outputs data from the 1st column to console - but you can replace it with your own logic

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect to the Access database.
2. [Fetch](http://p2p.wrox.com/ado-net/28703-how-vbulletin-net-connect-access-database.html) the records using your SELECT… query.
3. Load the result into a List of your Custom class object (e.g: Customer) /Data Table /Data Set.
4. Write a loop (For / [For Each](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx)) to iterate through each record and do the comparison with whatever you want to.

Try this yourself. If you encounter any errors, post that as a seperate question with relevant details.

Comment: Can someone provide an example of looping through and updating each record one by one?