# How do I loop through an MS SQL database with VB.NET?

Tags: php, sql, vb.net

I'm trying to implement the following php code in visual basic. I wrote it in PHP because I knew I could do what I wanted to in that language, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it working in Visual Basic to loop through a MS SQL database.

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'FakeDB');

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM FakeDB");
$concatDupes = Array();
for ( $i = 0, $i< count($result), $i++) {
    if ( $result[$i] == $result[$i + 1] {
         array_push($concatDupes,$result[$i] + $result[$i + 1])
    } else {
            array_push( $concatDupes, $result[$i])
    }
}
```

I've tried to use the code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729479/vb-net-looping-through-access-database) but to no avail.  (I put `MsgBox("hello")` inside the `while` loop and nothing happened) I've also attempeted the following, also with zero success.

```
Dim i = Me.PaymentTableAdapter.GetData().HazWasteAmtColumn.ToString()
MsgBox(i) 'no message box
Dim i = Me.PaymentTableAdapter.GetData().Count
MsgBox(i) ' also no message box
Dim i = Me.PaymentTableAdapter.GetData().Count
MsgBox(GetType(i)) 'type of i is not defined
```

I know my query is returning results because it works fine in a DataGridView.

Other useful info:

- Watching the `i` (any of the `i`'s referenced above) always shows Nothing, no matter what I've tried.
- Here's what happens when I call `Public Sub ReadData(ByVal connectionString As String, ByVal queryString As String)` (full function in linked page) with:

  ```
  Dim connect = WindowsApplication1.My.Settings.ShopMgtConnectionString
  Dim querty As String = "SELECT * "
  querty = querty + "FROM SM.PartItem "
  ReadData(connect, querty)
  ```

  immediate window output (the error list shows nothing):

  ```
  A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
  A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
  A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
  A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.ConstraintException' occurred in System.Data.dll
  A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
  ```

EDIT: Here's the ReadData() method

```
Public Sub ReadData(ByVal connectionString As String, _
    ByVal queryString As String)
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand(queryString, connection)

        connection.Open()

        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Console.WriteLine(reader(0).ToString())
        End While
        reader.Close()
    End Using 
End Sub
```

EDIT, Again...
I've taken a screen recording of the program running. It's just not doing anything useful.

http://youtu.be/i7oNVDXUw78

Comment: what does your `ReadData()` method look like!!!!!?

Comment: It's in the linked page, but I'll add it to this post

Comment: well, its the most important part of the post.

Comment: you mean there is no issue?

Comment: no, I fixed the missing method in the post. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: one thing i see is your are blindly reading the column info and doing a `.ToString()`, are there `NULL`s?

Comment: other comments, using OleDb.. you definitely want to wrap your `Command` and `Reader` objects in `using` blocks.  They will leak.

Comment: Ok. What do you recommend instead? I can avoid `NULL`s. I'm new to the VB.NET thing, so I'm not sure why `NULL`s matter.

Comment: you can't fire a `.ToString()` on nothing.  I will post an answer, let's see if it helps...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are reading non null data:

```
While reader.Read()
   If reader.IsDBNull(0) = False Then
     Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0).ToString())
   End If
End While
```

Comment: No dice. Would replacing `Console.WriteLine()` with `MsgBox()` affect anything? Also, does the fact that I'm trying to connect to a `.mdf` file change anything?

Comment: the mdf?  isn't that a SQL Server DB?  Your `Connect()` would fail if your connection wasn't working.

Comment: you are missing part of the stack trace, post the complete stacktrace and indicate the line that is failing.

Comment: ok, I updated my answer, I was missing `.GetValue(0)` try that.

Comment: Is the immediate window the stack trace? If so, you've got it all.

Comment: no, that's incomplete...  did you try the latest change?

Comment: I promise you I posted all of it. I tried the latest change to no avail. The immediate window only says `A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll` about 10 times

Comment: I've posted a video of the program on Youtube. Its literally doing nothing.

Comment: you can't worry about the immediate window first chance exceptions.  If you are getting an exception in your application, that's what you should be concerned with.

Comment: That makes sense. I tossed an `else` on the end of your `if` to let me know if something it caught a `null` or any other things. I got nothing.

Comment: what is the first column of the select?  i stay away from SELECT * because it leads to trouble... select one column, one you know has data.

Comment: The first column is the primary key for the table. There are no null values there. I've modified the query to eliminate possible speed problems. I've narrowed it to return only 100 results that I know exist.
`SELECT PartItemId FROM SM.PartItem WHERE PartItemId < 100`

EDIT: no dice. and no errors aside from the immediate window.

Comment: Oh, I have no clue how much data it's returning since I'm getting nothing. I know the queries work because they load into a DataGridView, but that's it.

Comment: you are writing to the console... you sure you have a problem?

Comment: I've changed it to a message box, nothing...
I've changed it back to console, noting... 
Visual Studio 2012

Comment: I changed the connection string to the word cat and I get the same results. the immediate window shows `A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll` and nothing happens.